Banana Pi BPI-F3 Armbian Ethernet setup
I'm using a Banana Pi BPI-F3 with Armbian-unofficial 24.11.0-trunk sid. I'm able to connect to the Banana Pi by connecting an ethernet cable between my (Ubuntu) laptop and the board, and using the "shared with other computers" IPv4 setting in the Ubuntu network manager.
On the Banana Pi, I can see that it's able to complete DNS queries (e.g. running ping will resolve the address associated with a hostname), and I can connect to my laptop from the Banana Pi over the LAN just fine. However, I can't get it to connect to anything outside of my laptop, and the packets the Pi sends out don't seem to be forwarded onto the broader network.
When I run Wireshark, I can see that packets for ping google.com are being received by my laptop's ethernet interface, but they seem to be getting dropped.

Running route -n on the Banana Pi yields:

Is there anything else I can try to get a working internet connection?

Part of the issue was Docker on my host machine (which I just disabled using systemctl), and then following the Arch Wiki's instructions on setting up a shared internet connection was enough to get this working:
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o [wireless/internet facing interface] -j MASQUERADE
# iptables -I DOCKER-USER 1 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# iptables -I DOCKER-USER 2 -i [ethernet interface/connection to Banana Pi] -o [wireless/internet facing interface] -j ACCEPT

